# $F=w(x)=\frac{k}{x^2}$ How much work required to lift a satellite an "infinite distance" into outer space?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The satellite is 6000 lbs at earth's surface, a distance $R$ from the earth's centre (so the answer will be in terms of $R$).

I know that it's supposed to be an improper integral going from 0 (?) to $\infty$.

Here's how I have things now, am I on the right track? I'm confused about how to set it up.

$$\int_0^\infty\ \frac{6000R^2}{x^2}$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically on the right track, but you've set up the integral a little bit wrong (and omitted which variable you're integrating with). You've sort of plugged all your variables in, but not correctly. Firstly, your integral needs to be of the form:
$$\int_{R}^{\infty}w(x) \,dx$$
since you start at position $R$ and end at position $\infty$ while resisting a downwards force of $w(x)$ - so those ought to be the bounds of integration.

Then, you need to determine the constant $k$ in $w(x)=\frac{k}{x^2}$. In particular, you know that the weight at the Earth's surface is 6000 lbs which means, in particular, that $w(R)=6000\text{ lbs}$. This can be expanded into an equation which you may solve for $k$.

Comment: I've solved for k and came up with this : k=6000R^2. So then should I be substituting that back in for k in the original equation? That led me to the way I had it set up (here I've fixed the bounds), as  $\int_R^\infty\ \frac{6000R^2}{x^2}$

Comment: @Keenan Oh! I really should have actually worked through the problem before writing an answer - but yes, I think that new form is correct - the important bit is not to integrate from $0$

Comment: How does one go about solving an integral with two variables like that?

Comment: Wait, never mind... it'll be in terms of R.... duh. Thank you!

Comment: I'm actually having trouble figuring out this integral now. How do you integrate 6000 $\int_R^\infty\ \frac{R^2}{x^2}dx$ ?

Comment: @Keenan You can pull out $R^2$ too - is $6000R^2\int_{R}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ easier for you?

Comment: Are you sure I can pull out R? It's not a constant, is it? @Meelo

Comment: @Keenan In that integral it is constant - you're not integrating with respect to $R$. Consider that you are picking $R$ to be some constant before you do anything with the problem, and then for the rest, it will not change - so it's just standing in for an unknown number.

Answer (score 0):

You want $$Work \ Integral = \int_{R_E}^\infty Force(x). dx = \int_{R_E}^\infty \frac{GM_Em}{x^2} dx = \frac{GM_Em}{R_E}$$ where $R_E$ is the radius of the Earth, $M_E$ is the mass of of the Earth, $G$ is the universal gravitational constant and $m$ is the mass of the object you are moving from the surface of the Earth to 'infinity'.

Comment: What are G and M?